# Android: HttpClient remote vs. local server

Tags: android, httpclient

I'm having problems with an app that works when connecting to a remote web server, running a php script against a database. However, when I point the same app to my local web server running on my machine, things doesn't work.

Here's the code I use for connecting to the remote web server (it needs authentication):

(All the networking code is done inside an AsyncTask class.)

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
StringBuilder authentication = new   
    StringBuilder().append("frankh").append(":").append("vriceI29");
result = Base64.encodeBytes(authentication.toString().getBytes());
httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + result);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("date", date));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
is = entity.getContent();
```

For the connection to the local server, which doesn't use authentication, I'm commenting out these lines:

```
//StringBuilder authentication = new   
//    StringBuilder().append("frankh").append(":").append("vriceI29");
//result = Base64.encodeBytes(authentication.toString().getBytes());
//httppost.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + result);
```

However, I get two different errors, depending on how I phrase the url to the local web server.

If I use this url: "http://localhost.shoppinglistapp/fetchlist.php"

I get this error:

```
Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: localhost.shoppinglistapp
```

If I skip the http part in the url, I get this error:

```
Error in http connectionjava.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null,
or set in parameters.
```

What am I doing wrong here? The remote server is a Linux Apache server, and the local server is IIS 7. The local server is supposed to be just for working on when I've got no or a bad internet connection, so it's not critical, but I hate not knowing why things doesn't work.

Comment: Are you testing on device or emulator?

Comment: ``localhost.shoppinglistapp/fetchlist.php`` should this read ``localhost/shoppinglistapp/fetchlist.php``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you testing via your local emulator, you'll want to use 10.0.2.2 instead of 'localhost'.

[Referring to localhost from the emulated environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

Comment: Thanks, that was the solution :)